# Запретить удаление using

Tags: c#

Есть код:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
                 .Enrich.FromLogContext()
#if DEBUG == false
                 .WriteTo.File(rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                               rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                               shared: true,
                               outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                               path: string.Concat(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Logs\Log.log"),
                               encoding: Encoding.UTF8)
#endif
                 .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                 .CreateLogger();
```

в котором для работы нужно подключение `using System.Text`. Во время работы я перед публикацией проекта пользуюсь "Анализ и очистка кода"->"Запустить очистку кода", которая из-за выбранного `Debug` удаляет `using System.Text`. Соответственно, приходится каждый раз заново писать, т.к. появляется ошибка компиляции при попытке опубликовать решение (т.к. публикация решения делается в `Release`).

Вопрос: Как отключить удаление при очистке кода именно этого `using`'а?

Comment: что мешает обернуть `using` в такой же `#if`?

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо за подсказку. Можете оформить это в виде ответа - поставлю галочку

Comment: Как вариант, добавить `System.Text` в `global using`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Украду ответ у @Grundy*

Заверните `using` в такое же условие.

```
#if DEBUG == false
using System.Text;
#endif
```